# Android can't show UI design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I created my app and wrote some code in activity_main.xml file. I have receiptdesign to do what I wanted, but when I run the project in emulator or a device, it does not show my design, only black windows.
I think the problem is my xml file, but I do not know what I'm doing wrong. This is my source:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="#ff0000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook_back_img"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="13.8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook_avatar_circle_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/facebook_back_img"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
        android:textColor="#fcf7e8"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rounded_image"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refresh_list"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/user_score"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rounded_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rounded_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook_circle"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rounded_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook_avatar_circle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/facebook_back_img"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#edf2f8"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_to_store"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bilboard" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_to_camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/go_to_store"
        android:background="@drawable/fan_page" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your activity onCreate

Answer (score 1):

I have a pretty good guess of what went wrong, though I won't know for sure until you upload the actual JAVA code. In every android activity's JAVA file, there should be a statement called set content view to the XML file. If this is not specified, then the Java file and the Android Activity will not know what XML file to load and what content to show, so a blank screen will be shown.

I hope that helps; sorry if the answer is rough, this is the first question I have responded to on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Use comments section for comments. Do not post Upvote or accept requests in the answer. - Rolled back edit